# Java: JTextField won't appear

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
public class HandleUI {     
    public static void setUpUI(){   
        JPanel jPan = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
        jPan.setLayout(flow);           
        txtFld = new JTextField();
        txtFld.setSize(550,5);
        jPan.add(txtFld);
        jPan.setSize(10,200);
        MainClass.mainFrame.add(jPan);
        int gapX = MainClass.mainFrame.getX()-(txtFld.getX()/2);
    }   
    //Instance variables.
    public static JTextField txtFld;
    public JButton [] buttons;
}   
public class MainClass { 
    public static void main (String [] args){           
        int frameX = Constants.FRAME_WIDTH;
        int frameY = Constants.FRAME_HEIGHT;
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(frameX,frameY);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        HandleUI.setUpUI(); 
    }
    //Instance variables
    public static JFrame mainFrame;
}
```

It's supposed to show `JTextField`, but as you might have guessed - `JFrame` shows nothing. I didn't type in imports on purpose, but they are all there. I can't find the problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

**1.)** Simply write:

```
JTextField tField = new JTextField(10);
```

Here In the constructor you are passing the number of columns, which is sufficient for a layout like `FlowLayout` to set the size of the `JTextField`

**2.)** The line `mainFrame.setVisible(true);` must be the last line of the main method. You need to put the code at `main()` method, inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` thingy.

**3.)** Instead of setting size on the `JFrame` use `JFrame.pack()`, to set the window to the preferred size.

**4.)** Creation of unnecessary `static` members is a design flaw. Try to keep yourself away from such thingies.

**5.)** Read a bit about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

One Example Program for help(**Use the order of lines as specified in this answer**):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JTextField tField = new JTextField(10);
        contentPane.add(tField);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example().displayGUI();
            }           
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: write it instead of line : txtFld = new JTextField(); ?

Comment: @user3754221:  Calling empty constructor, for `FlowLayout` will create a very small `JTextField` I guess, moreover, `frame.setVisible(true)` should have to be the last line, preceeded by `frame.pack()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `setVisible(true)` on your `JFrame` **AFTER** having initialised your UI.

Simply pulling the following line:

```
HandleUI.setUpUI();
```

... right before:

```
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

... will do the trick.

As a side note, I'd like to point out that setting the size of your text field won't really work like you did. You probably would use `setPreferredSize(Dimension)` instead. Or, even better, organise your UI only using Layouts and not manually setting any component's size.

Comment: So basically setVisible() method has to be last that does something with JPanel?